# How to display multiple forms of a single model in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I have this model Note:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And I want to display this form:

```
class NoteEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('title', 'text')
```

in a template, but I want it to appear for **each** existing Note object in the database (it has to be that way). I've done something like that but then I hardcoded the form, pointing to the edit view URL with each object pk as a parameter; but I'm sure it has to be a clearer way, just I haven't found it. Could you guys help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/) (also see [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)).

For your Note model and NoteEditForm you could do something like this. You'd usually put this wherever you've defined your NoteEditForm but it can go in another file, such as `views.py`.

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
NoteEditFormSet = modelformset_factory(Note, form=NoteEditForm)
```

Using `NoteEditFormSet` in a view and template is almost the same as using a regular form, but there are a few differences to be aware of if you want to do anything complicated so have a look at the docs ([view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view) and [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template)). If that's not clear enough, add a few details of what you're trying to do in your view and template and I'll try to help.

By default the formset will use `Note.objects.all()` as its queryset, which is what you say you want, but you can change that (details are covered in the docs).

### Update:

To save an individual Note with an AJAX request I would add a second view to handle those requests. So if your formset for all Notes is served by a view at `/notes/`, you could add a view to handle your AJAX request at `/notes/<note_id>/` (obviously just an example, adjust to fit your URL structure).

Then your JS on the `/notes/` page is responsible for serializing the data for a single note and making the request to `/notes/<note_id>/` (remember the CSRF token).

The HTML inputs generated for the formset have their IDs prefixed with something like `id_form-<number>-` and there are hidden inputs containing Note primary keys which will let you work out which ID prefix applies to each note.

Comment: Man, that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I want to make AJAX request to save an individual form without having to reload the page. I know how to do it with a single form, but can I achieve that with formsets as well?

Comment: @JuliánBonilla I added some info on saving individual instances using AJAX. It's not a comprehensive guide but if you already know how to do it for a single form then you probably don't need a full tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I would think about doing it like this

```
{% for note in Notequeryset %}
    <form action={% url 'url_name_to_form' pk={{note.pk}} %}>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know what you think